# Driving servo motor using open cv

Tags: robotics, servo, detection

I'm working on a object detection robot project.I'm using open cv software to detect objects.
My question is how can i take open cv outputs(x-y coordinates) to servo motor.and how can i interface computer ports using open cv.

Comment: You'll want to create a world view coordinate system and then keep track of objects relative to the robot's position.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little vague, but maybe I can provide some info that will allow you to improve the quality of your post.

I'm assuming that you have the OpenCV portion working, and you indeed get X/Y position values.  If you have OpenCV working, then I assume you can also link to its binaries from your compiler.  For example, you can add references to the .NET build of OpenCV (emgucv) in Visual Studio.  Your own app will then be able to get the X/Y values.

At this point, you now need to control your servo motor.  You could interface with it in several ways.  One way is to get a dedicated servo motor driver / controller that communicates with your PC over a variety of physical formats -- RS232, CAN, USB, Ethernet, Ethercat, are some examples.  If you have one of these, there is most likely a library that you can also link your application to to control the motor.

Another option is to use an Arduino, a proper motor shield, and then connect your Arduino to your PC via the USB connection.  This becomes a virtual COM port and you'll then need to implement your own RS-232 communication protocol to send commands to the Arduino.  The code running on the Arduino would then parse these incoming commands, and then control the motors via the motor shield.

If you can make your question more specific, you will likely get even more help from people here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the question is a little vague but I will try my best to help. I'm assuming you can get your x-y coordinates just fine through your object detection code, and therefore am also assuming you can determine the angle at which you want your servo motor. I think the easiest way is to get your PC to talk to a separate processor (microcontroller, FPGA) through some sort of communication protocol through your PC ports (rs232, USB, parallel port). The Arduino is a nice easy start to this as it has a built in Servo library to drive servo motors along with simple UART communication protocol.

Like Dave said, you're going to have to implement your own rs232 protocol to send the commands to the Arduino (if you choose to go this route). You could send the angle in just one byte (assuming 0 to 180 degrees). You could even add in start and end bytes just for a safer, more robust, communication protocol. You may also want the Arduino to send back acknowledgement (ACK) signal(s) to determine whether or not the data was received properly.

Now, OpenCV plays no part in using the comm ports on your PC. You can access the serial port (or any port) with Visual Studios. Here is a good tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Once you have the port opened correctly (generally, you'll want to have the serial port set at 8 bits, 1 stop bit, no parity if using the Arduino), communication is quite simple. You basically need to load the data you want to send into a character buffer and then use the WriteFile() method to send out that buffer. The method can even tell you how many bytes were written if you want to make sure the host end has sent out the data correctly. The ReadFile() method works very similarily. You can have the Arduino polling for data from the host-side and update the servo angle whenever data is received.